# DataGridView - what does AllowUserToAddRows do?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I was expecting this setting to affect the control itself, but I can't seem to add new rows just by having a DataGridView with AllowUserToAddRows set to true. Am I just rubbish at using my mouse and keyboard, or have I completely misunderstood this property? I suspect it's the latter, though I can't find much in the way of documentation to point me in the right direction.

EDIT: by the way, it's not that I'm rubbish, it seems to be something to do with using a List as the DataSource of the DataGridView; the little '*' just doesn't appear if I bind to a List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by changing STMTTRN from a List to a BindingList - List seems to have some very odd behaviour when used as a DataSource (see my other recent question, which is solved in the same way).

It's in generated code, but I'd already changed it from an Array to a List so BindingList is barely any extra trouble :)

Comment: "STMTTRN" - sounds like you're using OFX?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem for me as well, and `BindingList` did not solve it, but merlin's answer gave me a hint towards an eventual solution.

Wrapping the list in a `BindingSource` is an important part of the solution (as also documented in another question: [Can't Allow User To Add Rows to DataGridView with List<> Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565875/cant-allow-user-to-add-rows-to-datagridview-with-list-datasource)).

And for me, the missing step was that the class of **the objects in my list did not have a public parameterless constructor**. Adding a parameterless constructor enabled `AllowUserToAddRows` to function as expected.

I got the clue from an exception which was raised when I tried merlin's answer, the message of which suggests that it may also be possible to enable row adding by handling the `AddingNew` event:

> AddNew cannot be called on the 'MyType' type. This type does not have
>   a public default constructor. You can call AddNew on the 'MyType' type
>   if you handle the AddingNew event and create the appropriate object.

I did not try this, as fortunately adding a public parameterless constructor was no problem for me, but it is a message of hope for anyone else who cannot add a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Try it,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("No", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

EDIT:

Take a look at [IBindingList](http://www.nedcomp.nl/support/origdocs/dotnetsdk/cpref/frlrfsystemcomponentmodelibindinglistclasstopic.htm)

Comment: I tried your code and it worked, so thanks :) But I'm actually using a List as the DataSource, which (since it's the only difference) is probably the cause of my problem. Do you know why a List would make the 'add row' functionality not work?

Comment: Implements **IBindingList** interface.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

using a BindingSource as the DGV datasource and setting the BindingSource property AllowNew = True, solved my problem.

```
Dim binding As New BindingSource
binding.DataSource = myList
binding.AllowNew = True
With DataGridView1
    .AutoGenerateColumns = False
    .DataSource = binding
End With
```