# AllowUserToAddRows doesn't work with with List<> Datasource on DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a `DataGridView` with the `DataSource` set to `List<myClass>`

However, the new row indicator does not display when I set `AllowUserToAddRows` to `true`,

When I set the `DataSource` to `BindingList<myClass>`, that seems to solve the problem.

*Q*: Should replace my `List<>` with `BindingList<>` or there is better solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Does `myClass` have a public parameterless constructor? If not, you could derive from `BindingList<T>` and override `AddNewCore` to call your custom constructor.

(edit) Alternatively - just wrap your list in a `BindingSource` and it may work:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        var people = new List<Person> { new Person { Name = "Fred" } };
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = people;

        Application.Run(new Form { Controls = { new DataGridView {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill, DataSource = bs } } });
    }
}
```