# number of rows in datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a table in my datagridview and i have dynamically created textboxes in the same form.
I want to know the number of my columns and rows but its value is always showing 0

```
        int j = dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
        int k = dmrc.dataGridView2.ColumnCount; 

        for (int i = 0; i<=j+2; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Name = "tb"+i;
            txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 , 18 +(25*i));
            txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
            this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= j+2; i++)
        {
            TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Name = "tb" +i;

            txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, 18 + (25* i));
            txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
            txtRun.Text = Convert.ToString(j); 
            this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
        }
```

BEFORE THIS I HAD MADE A OleDB CONNECTION TO IMPORT EXCEL FILE

try
            {

```
            DataGridView dataGridview2 = new DataGridView();
            dmrc dmrc = new dmrc();

            string pathconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path.Text + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathconn);

            OleDbDataAdapter mydata = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + sheet.Text + "$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            mydata.Fill(dt);





            dmrc.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            dmrc.Show();



            int j = dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < j ; i++)
                {


                    string StrQuery = "INSERT INTO " + textBox1.Text + " VALUES ('" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + "' , '" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[16].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[17].Value + "','" + dmrc.dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[18].Value + "');";

                    try
                    {
                        string myConne = "datasource=localhost;database=dmrc;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
                        MySqlConnection conne = new MySqlConnection(myConne);
                        conne.Open();

                        using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(StrQuery, conne))
                        {
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        conne.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
```

IN THIS BUTTON MY ROWS.COUNT IS WORKING PERFECT BUT NOT IN THE PREVIOUS ONE

Comment: i always get j = 0 and k = 0 .. how to resolve this..??

Comment: Are you sure you actually have columns and rows??

Comment: yepp..i have 1 column and 6 rows in it

Comment: Nah, there is something else. What is `dmrc`? Both either `Rows.Count` and `RowsCount` and `ColumnCount` and `Column.Count` will give the true numbers. The difference is you can use the 'undotted' properties to also __change__ the numbers. I guess you are looking at a wrong object..

Comment: dmrc is the object of my form to access the datagridview.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like it may be the problem: Are you __declaring__ the DGV there, too,  or are you really just pointing to the true DGV with the data?? IOW: Are you __hiding__ the real DGV by the declaration of dmrc.dataGridView2?

Comment: I dint get you..what should I do..?

Comment: i got it i got it.. i removed dmrc and it worked..thanks for helping

Comment: please help me in this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743963/displaying-data-from-multiple-tables-in-datagridview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to remember is that an "empty" datagridview has 1 record only if the AllowUsersToAddRow property is set to true. Otherwise, the row count will be 0.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612791/datagridview-rowcount-vs-rows-count)

I think you're also confused on the syntax to retrieve the `Count` ..

```
DataGridView1Name.Rows.Count
```

Comment: and it is not empty..it has 1 column and 6 rows in it

Comment: and do i need to make any sort of connection before using this code..?

Comment: @user3808299 I must be confused. I don't see you loading *any* data into your DataGridView.

Comment: please view my above code.. the import is successful and the Rows.Count is working properly in that..but its not working in another button

Comment: Unless there is a reason unbeknownst to me, you should not have anything before `dataGridView2`. Why is `dmrc` necessary? Try your counts without it.

Comment: plesase help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743963/displaying-data-from-multiple-tables-in-datagridview