# displaying data from multiple tables in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, append

I have a list of tables in one column n checkboxes in another column. I want to view data of the tables which I select by clicking on the checkboxes

My code is

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++ )
        {
            if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
            {
                if ((Boolean)dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string myConnection="datasource=localhost;database=dmrc;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
                        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
                        string query = "select * from dmrc." + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        MySqlCommand cmdDatabas = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn);
                        MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdDatabas;
                        DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                        myDataAdapter.Fill(dbdataset);
                        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                        bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                        f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                        myDataAdapter.Update(dbdataset);
                        f1.Show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

But each time it shows the data of 1 table only. What should I change and where..?

Answer (score 0):

Before this question can be answered can you please confirm
1) if dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1] is the checkbox column 
2) dataGridView1 is another grid where you want to display the tables one below the other
3) Do the tables that form the datasource of dataGridView1 have the same columns in the same order?
As the information provided isn't sufficient.

If, and only if, the "select *" gives the same columns in the same order, you can add multiple tables. Create an empty datatable (lets call it master) before the for loop. In each iteration, merge the new datatable dbdataset to the master datatable. You can view the syntax here: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f122d7f4-3b7d-4d93-bd0f-8bb57cd990a4/how-to-join-two-datatables-using-c-no-database-access?forum=adodotnetdataset). This gives details on how you can handle your columns and primary keys. Custom modifications in datatable can also be done AFTER you have built it. The syntax is here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcs3hdk5(v=vs.110).aspx).
Hope this helps!

```
DataTable masterdbdataset = new DataTable();
//Perform custom operations here if necessary
    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            if ((Boolean)dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string myConnection="datasource=localhost;database=dmrc;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
                    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
                    string query = "select * from dmrc." + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    MySqlCommand cmdDatabas = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn);
                    MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdDatabas;
                    DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                    myDataAdapter.Fill(dbdataset);
                    myDataAdapter.Update(dbdataset);
                    masterdbdataset.Merge(dbdataset);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
}
    bSource.DataSource = masterdbdataset;
    f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
    f1.Show();
```

Comment: yes..cells[1] is the checkbox

dataGridView1 is another grid

Comment: Ok, so the problem seems to be here: 
f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
Each iteration of the loop simply scans the next table and resets the contents in the dataGridView1 with the current table's rows. What you probably wanna do is to "append" rows to your dataGridView1.

Comment: Yes..it is replacing the new table with the previous one and displaying the current table.. bt how to append it so that I can view multiple tables..?

Comment: it did not help me..please suggest something else

Comment: I might have confused you with the very verbose links. But they are good for going through once to have a better understanding. I have added the code but I have not run it on a machine so please run this in debug mode in case of errors. The idea is to have masterdbdataset store all the data and with each iteration the number of rows in  this should increase. I know I have been saying this a lot but only for the sake of its importance - your queries must return the same columns in the same order for 'merge' function to work. Handle primary keys in a custom logic if required.

Comment: its not working .. its showing only 1 table as it was showing before