# Storing datatable values into datagrid Then grid count is default incresed by one in C#.net WindowsForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to store datatable values into datagrid

```
int dtCount=datatable.Rows.Count;(7)
 dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
```

but After assing the datagrid Count is not same as datatable how to fix it?

```
  int i2 = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;(8)
```

using C3.net in windows forms
Please Reply as early as possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `BindingSource.ResetBindings` method?

Comment: Look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612791/datagridview-rowcount-vs-rows-count

Comment: Turn off `AllowUserToAddRows`!

Comment: Thanks Taw it Was Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

That's because the datatable has a so called zero based index and the datagridview has not.
All your items should be in the datagridview, it's just counted differently.

So, briefly, the datatable starts counting from 0 but the datagridview starts counting from 1.

Comment: Thanks For Responce I have Solved By Disable AllowUserToAddRows