# DataGridView's new row isn't showing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `Phone` class:

```
class Phone
{
    public string Number { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public Phone(string number, string description)
    {
        Number = number;
        Description = description;
    }
}
```

I tried to bind a `List<Phone>` to a `DataGridView`:

```
var list = new List<Phone>
{
    new Phone("(00) 000-000-000", "Personal"),
    new Phone("(11) 111-111-111", "Work"),
};
dataGridView.DataSource = list;
```

The data is bonded perfectly. However, even though the `AllowUserToAddRows` property is set to `true`, I am unable to add a new row. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422340/1925272) answer, I tried to use a `BindingList` instead, but I get the same results.

**Example:**

[image: New row doesn't show]

Comment: make your list a `BindingList<>` instead.

Comment: You are going to need a simple constructor

Comment: @Crowcoder - Thanks. As I wrote in the question, I have tried that.

Comment: @Plutonix - what do you mean by "simple" constructor?

Comment: A ctor that requires no params - nobody but you knows how to use the one there.  Adding a row means creating a new (empty) Item, but the control/collection wont have any data for those params

Comment: oops. I should read it. You can set allow add rows on the binding list too. Did you try that?

Comment: @Crowcoder, your combined solutions works, thanks. However, it requires `Phone` to have a public setter. Is there any workaround?

Comment: I don't think you can have private setters if you want to make data modifications to those properties.

Comment: Why display a list in a user-editable grid if you dont want changes to be made after it is created? And you cant add new ones that way either.

Comment: Well, I wasn't sure how this data binding works. I thought maybe every change you make creates another object or something.