# AllowUserToAddRow Property not working in .NET / C# (DataGridView)

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, binding

I have a DataGridView linked to a BindingSource

- *AllowUserToAddRow* property is set to true for the DGV
- *AllowNew* property is set to true for the binding source
- There are no conflicts with the *ReadOnly* property of the datagridview

I tried to add a parameter less, public constructor for the type referenced in the binding source, which didn't work either.

PS : I use the *ToBindingList()* and not the *ToList()* method to affect the datasource.

In the designer, the DGV show the blank line with a star (which showcases the ability to add a row), but it disappears once running the project, so I can't add any row in the DGV.

Any clue about that?

Comment: There are other questions on this matter. Not sure if they can help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422001/datagridview-what-does-allowusertoaddrows-do or

Comment: Thanks, but i already saw that question and it didn't solve my problem. The weird thing is that is show the blanck line with the star * on the designer, but it diseappers as soon as I run the code.